# Can I order a pivot table using a second condition?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I am working with a spreadsheet where I store the books I read. The format is as follows:

```
 A   |  B    |   C    |  D   |   E      |    F
year | book  | author | mark | language | country of the author
```

With entries like:

```
 A   |  B                 |   C         | D | E   |   F
-------------------------------------------------------------
2004 | Hamlet              | Shakespeare | 8 | ES  | UK
2005 | Crimen y punishment | Dostoevsky  | 9 | CAT | Russia
2007 | El mundo es ansí    | Baroja      | 8 | ES  | Spain
2011 | Dersu Uzala         | Arsenyev    | 8 | EN  | Russia 
2015 | Brothers Karamazov  | Dostoevsky  | 8 | ES  | Russia
2019 | ... Shanti Andía    | Baroja      | 7 | ES  | Spain
```

I have several pivot tablas to get different data, such as top countries, top books, etc. In one of them I want to group by authors and order by number of books I have read from each one of them.

So I defined:

ROWS

- `author` (column C) with

  - order: Desc for `COUNT of author`

VALUES

- `author`

  - summation by: `COUNT`
  - show as `Default`
- `mark`

  - summation by: `AVERAGE`
  - show as `Default`

This way, the data above show like this:

```
 author      | COUNT of author | AVERAGE of mark
-------------------------------------------------------------
Baroja      |        2         | 7,5
Dostoevsky  |        2         | 8,5
Shakespeare |        1         | 8
Arsenyev    |        1         | 8
```

It is fine, since it orders data having top read authors on top. However, I would also like to order also by `AVERAGE of mark`. This way, when `COUNT of author` matches, it would use `AVERAGE of mark` to solve the ties and put on top the one author with a better average on their books.
On my sample data, Dostoevsky would go above Baroja (8,5 > 7).

I have been looking for different options, but I could not find any without including an extra column in the pivot table.

How can I use a second option to solve the ties when the first option gives the same value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve a **customized sort order on a pivot table** without any extra columns in the source range. However... you'd definately need an extra field added to the pivot.

In the Pivot table editor go to **Values** and add a `Calculated Field`.

> [image: Values - new calculated field]

Use any formula that describes the sort order you want. E.g. let's multiply the counter by 100 to use as first criteria:

```
=COUNTA(author) * 100 + AVERAGE(score)
```

- Do notice it is **important** to select `Summarize by` your `Custom` formula (screenshot above).

Now, just add this new calculated field as your row's `Sort by` field, and you're done!

> [image: First Column - sort by Calculated Field 1]

---

---

Notice though, you do get an extra column added to the pivot.

> [image: The whole sheet showing the pivot with the calculated field as new column]

Of course, you could hide it.

> [image: same as before with hidden column]

---

> Translated from [my answer](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/399636/193460) to the cross-posted question on es.SO.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(A2:F, 
 "select C,count(C),avg(D)
  where A is not null 
  group by C
  order by count(C) desc
  label C'author',count(C)'COUNT of author',avg(D)'AVERAGE of mark'")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Oh thanks! I guess you need an extra order, since Baroja shows on top of Dostoevsky

Comment: you can add orders as you wish. example: `=QUERY(A2:F, 
 "select C,count(C),avg(D)
  where A is not null 
  group by C
  order by count(C) desc, avg(D) desc
  label C'author',count(C)'COUNT of author',avg(D)'AVERAGE of mark'")`